# Spitting Character String then Pasting it together

Tags: r, string, concatenation

I was manipulating my count-data (fcm) and had my Barcode ID's as column names in the format:  TCGA.BH.A0DQ.11A.12R.A089.07 etc

I proceeded to use:

```
CountCol= colnames(fcm)
 Barcode = strsplit(as.character(CountCol), ".", fixed=TRUE)
```

giving me a list of all the split character strings such as :

```
head(Barcode,2)
[[1]]
[1] "TCGA" "3C"   "AAAU" "01A"  "11R"  "A41B" "07"  

[[2]]
[1] "TCGA" "3C"   "AALI" "01A"  "11R"  "A41B" "07"
```

My question is now how do I put only the first three elements together to make new column names separated by a "-" (i.e. TCGA-3C-AAAU for the first and so forth for the next ~1200 values)

I hope this was clear.
I tried a few methods but keep coming short of the correct solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `sapply`

```
sapply(Barcode,function(x){paste(x[1:3],collapse="-")})
```

Comment: perfect. I had tried that but I kept trying complex paste functions with  for loops etc haha.. thats simple and it does exactly what I want. thank you

Comment: learn about apply functions, they're great :). Also if your barcodes are always the same length you could also combine `gsub` and `substr` to get your output

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `purrr`library for a more simplified code:

```html
library(purrr)

x <- c("TCGA", "3C",   "AAAU", "01A",  "11R",  "A41B", "07" )
y <- c("TCGA", "3C",   "AALI", "01A",  "11R",  "A41B", "07" )
z <- list(x, y)

purrr::map(z, ~paste(.[1:3], collapse = "-"))

[[1]]
[1] "TCGA-3C-AAAU"

[[2]]
[1] "TCGA-3C-AALI"
```

Comment: Which in base R speak is `Map(paste, lapply(z,head,3), collapse="-")`